# Need help to understand what is making my question too broad

Tags: support, reopen-closed

[This is my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36381832). There seems to be very relevant answer to the question as well.

What makes the question too broad? Do you find the question/title misleading? What needs to be added to improve the question in specific? Also, is the question giving any sense that it is missing any details? I have edited the question several times wanting to reopen it but it seems to be lying closed. I wanted help to understand if there is something missing in the question.

I also have [another edited question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976452). I have edited it as per guidelines. Is there any reopen-queue or undo-delete queue where I could post my link for undelete so that I can request for attention to undelete my question?

Comment: I think you produced a problem and want suggestion from us in your question. You should ask question that you really faced and also include what you have tried to solve.

Comment: worth noting that close happened at [rev 6](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36381832/6) of the question which looks quite different from current one. Also it is very likely that most close votes were cast on [first revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36381832/1): "Suppose I have 1000 items of n different types that I need to process. I can process them simultaneously but only one of each type can be processed at a time. What would be a good approach to build a data structure for this?" (that's a full text of rev 1)

Comment: I wouldn't take it personally, I think it near impossible to pass the numerous tests the moderators will put any post through. Some will think it's too broad, others may think it's too narrow. Some may think it's too off-topic, others may think it's too specifically on-topic. Some may think it's a duplicate, others may just think it's trash. That is what this community has become, people timidly asking if it is OK to ask this or that. Masters of pedanticness.

Comment: These closed questions have caused my account to be blocked. I am unable to post any questions unless these are opened.

Answer (score 1):

Some phrases from the first question ("Pool of unique locks"):

> What would be good way...
>   What is the best data-structure...
>   If you can suggest a better structure...

And one from the second question ("Java lambda performance"):

> Is there any way, I can optimize the lambda code

Such phrases usually spell trouble w.r.t. the scope of the question and it's hard to silence the alarm bells once they ring. Don't use such phrases. Try to zoom in on one specific programming problem you're actually struggling with.

On top of that, the first question doesn't contain any code, so it's not clear where you experience any trouble, and next, the second "rule" is a question, which makes the question unclear.

Another problem in the second question is the phrase

> The lambda code seems to be falling behind

That's not clear. Does it, or not? One vague statement can be enough for people to push the close button. It's not very challenging to solve a problem that may not even exist.

The first question is probably salvageable if you add code you tried yourself and clearly indicate where it fails. That may be hard though. It would probably be working code, making the question a candidate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

I doubt if the second question is salvageable. For one, you should clearly demonstrate a significant performance difference. Maybe you should ask if you're doing anything obviously wrong, specifically in the lambda statement.

In my experience, most people are really willing to help. But the problem should be clear and enable an answer that's right beyond opinion.